# What's the counterpart of np.clip in Julia?

Tags: julia

In Python, one can use `np.clip(arr, min, max)` to assign the `min` value to the elements lower than `min` and for `max` vice versa. I wonder If we have an identical counterpart in Julia?

Python:

```
>>> a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> np.clip(a, 1, 8)
array([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8])
```

I know in Julia we can say:

```
julia> a = collect(0:9);

julia> function clip!(array::VecOrMat, min, max)
         array[array.<min].=min
         array[array.>max].=max
         nothing
       end;

julia> clip!(a, 1, 8)

julia> a
10-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 8
```

I wonder if there is any built-in function for it?

Comment: Look at `clamp!`

Comment: @DanGetz, Thanks! https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.Math.clamp!

Comment: Maybe you can write your own answer to this one

Comment: `clamp!` is in-place. Use `clamp` for out-of-place.

Comment: A general tought: in Python you **need** to have a bult-in function for performance reasons. In Julia writing your own is perfectly fine as it wouldn't encoure any penality, aside adding a few lines of code.

Comment: @DanGetz, seems so.

Comment: @DNF, Yes, Dan suggested `clamp!` since I defined `clip!`.

Comment: @Antonello, sure Anto, I guess `clip!` isn't bad. Just I asked it in the case of curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: [`clamp!`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.Math.clamp!) (`clamp` is also available)